# Is reflection helpful?

Tags: java, reflection

Sorry for the title...

I have a method like foo() used as shown below

```
public static <T> void foo(T fld1, T fld2) {
    // here i use some info from fld1 and some from fld2 in order
    // to do something
}
foo(a1.myField, a2.myField)
```

- I want to be sure at compile time that myField is really a field of an object
- I want to avoid the need to repeat `.myField` two times
- I want one can't call the method as `foo(a1.myField, a2.anotherField);`

I don't know if reflection is the answer for my problem.

I can write something like this:

```
static <C> void foo(C o1, C o2, String fieldName) {
    try {
        Object fld1 = o1.getClass().getField(fieldName).get(o1);
        Object fld2 = o2.getClass().getField(fieldName).get(o2);
        // here i use some info from fld1 and some from fld2 in order
        // to do something
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

but i can't check at compile time if fieldName is a valid field name for class C

It would be helpful to have a method

```
Field getField(Object field)
```

so that

```
getField(a1.myField)
```

is equal to

```
a1.getClass().getField("myField")
```

now i write this method:

```
public static <T> Field getField(T o, Object fld) {
    Field rv = null;
    try {
        Field[] fields = o.getClass().getFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            Object f = field.get(o);
            if (f==fld) {
                rv = field;
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return rv;
}
```

and use this way

```
getField(a1, a1.myField);
```

Thanks for any answer, Carlo

Comment: Does myField and anotherField return the same type ? Or what type they return ?

Comment: myField and anotherField are the same type (else i get a compile error) but i want to avoid this. I want fld1 and fld2 be the same field of two different instances of the same class

Answer (score 2):

you can do check with `instanceOf` in method at run time.

**just example:**

```
if(fd1 instanceOf Fd1Obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be sure at compile time ..

Reflection is all about **runtime**.
So it is not helpful for **compile** time.

Comment: i know, but maybe it can help not for compile time but to check the constraints

Answer (score 0):

How about a static generic for making sure it's an object:

```
static <T extends Object> void foo(T fld1, T fld2) {
   // ...
}
```

You can use reflections to get a named field from the object:

```
AType myField1 = (AType)fld1.getClass().getField("myField").get(fld1);
AType myField2 = (AType)fld2.getClass().getField("myField").get(fld2);
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand. fld1 and fld2 are the fields so i can't do `fld1.getClass().getField("myField")` in the class of fld1 there isn't a "myField" field.

Comment: I changed my question with somothing you suggest so you can see why its not an answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type when invoking the foo(..) like:

> yourClass.foo(a1.myField, a2.myField).

This way you can be sure that the type checking is done at compile.

However, this is not mandatory, if you do not provide the type argument i.e.  in this case, the java documentation says that:

> the inference algorithm tries to find the most specific type that
>   works with all of the arguments.

have a look here:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

And No reflection won't be that good of a help for compile time checks.

Comment: I think my question is not clear enough... the foo() method is static and not relate to a specific class.

Comment: The static method belongs to a class and not to any specific instance. So when you invoke it you can provide the type arguments. I hope i am getting you.

Comment: Sorry but... i want fld1 and fld2 are the same field of two different instances of the same class (but i don't know and i don't care which is that class)

Answer (score 0):

This is verbose in Java, but Java8's lambdas should make it less so. What you need is a compile-time-checked way of getting from an object of type C to some value of type T. The way to specify that in Java is an interface:

```
public interface Getter<C, T> {
  T get(C c);
}
```

Then you specify your function as

```
static <C, T> void foo(C c1, C c2, Getter<C, T> getter) {
  T fld1 = getter.get(c1);
  T fld2 = getter.get(c2);
  // ...
}
```

And you call it like this - this is the part that's annoyingly verbose:

```
foo(a1, a2, new Getter<A, Integer>() {
    public Integer get(A a) { return a.fieldName; }
});
```

Java8's lambdas will make this dramatically more readable:

```
foo(a1, a2, a -> a.fieldName);
```